# In a If/Else should you use a blank return to exit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, return-type

> /***Update**/
>
> > **I agree with the answers to check for `newVal`'s existence... but if you had to choose one of the options, which is the less of the
> >     evils?**

I was going through a tutorial and saw the below code used #1.  I believe I have this right... What happens is if a `newVal` is passed update a database.  If !not exit function.  I have listed the variation I thought of... The question I have is what is best to use and why or is there a better way not listed? https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/real-time-web-apps-with-angularjs-and-firebase/lessons/on-value

The tutorial I am doing is setting the ng-model message.text to the database value first - then using watch updates the value afterwards. The !newVal is to stop it from updating before a value is enter I believe.  Direct quote: "Make sure the new value isn’t undefined because when the page loads the new value with be undefined."

1. if has blank return + no else

> ```
> $scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
>   if (!newVal){return;}
>   childRef.update({
>     text: newVal
>   });
> });
> ```

2. if has blank return + else

> ```
>  $scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
>           if (!newVal){return;}
>           else{
>             childRef.update({
>               text: newVal
>             });
>           }
>         });
> ```

3. if has no return and use an else

> ```
>  $scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
>           if (!newVal){}
>           else{
>             childRef.update({
>               text: newVal
>             });
>           }
>         });
> ```

4. if has no return and no else - which I don't think works

> ```
>  $scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
>           if (!newVal){}
>             childRef.update({
>               text: newVal
>             });
>         });
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why don't you use 
if(newVal){ childRef.... }?

Comment: @LucasCordina  The tutorial I am doing uses the !newVal to set the ng-model message.text to the database value first - then using watch updates the value afterwards.  The !newVal is to stop it from updating before a value is enter I believe.  I was just curious to know if you should be using returns with else(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or even shorter

```
$scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal) {
    newVal && childRef.update({
        text: newVal
    });
});
```

To make it clear, I use short circuit return(s) id there are more than one comparison after.

But this

```
if (!newVal) {
    return;
} else {
    // do something
}
```

is not necessary, because return ends the continuing. So better is

```
if (!newVal) {
    return;
}
// do something
```

Answer (score 3):

If statements should use the affirmative when possible, it is less confusing.

```
$scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal) {
  if(newVal) {
    childRef.update({
      text: newVal
    });
  }
});
```

**I interpret your examples as:**

`If not newVal do nothing, if not not newVal do something`

**Whereas I interpret my example as:**

`If newVal do something`

Much more easy to understand.

============================

In regards to using return or not. It is not necessary as **javascript** will be default to `return undefined;`

Comment: I completely agree with your answer... but if you had to choose one of the options, which is the less of the evils?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
$scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
  if (newVal) {
    childRef.update({
      text: newVal
    });
  }
});
```

which is the clearest for me.

In my opinion, the first one, which just "jumps out" of the function is a bad practice. I would always put the rest of the code in an else branch, so the code is more structured, it is clearly visible that the rest of the code is also conditional. This is closely related to function programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you *had* to choose one, the best one is:

```
$scope.$watch('message.text', function(newVal){
    if (!newVal) {
    } else {
        childRef.update({
            text: newVal
        });
    }
});
```

I would say, if you use return in one branch, then return in the other as well. A pure `return;` statement feels a bit useless. If you are expecting your code to return something, then you should write `return`s in every branch anyway, if you are not returning anything then i'd rather just leave all the `return`s.